# Sum of cosine reciprocals

Tags: trigonometry

'Prove and generalise the following: $$\frac {1}{\cos 0° \cos 15°} + \frac {1}{\cos 15° \cos 30°} + \frac {1}{\cos 30° \cos 45°} + \frac{1}{\cos 45° \cos 60°} + \frac {1}{\cos 60° \cos 75°} = \frac {\cos 15°}{\sin^2(15°)}$$

Apart from directly plugging it into the calculator, I have tried using multi-angle identities and grouping the terms, but I don't get anything meaningful. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Observe that $$15-0=30-15=45-30=\cdots=?$$

$$\dfrac{\sin(A-B)}{\cos A\cos B}=?$$

Comment: See also: math.stackexchange.com/questions/464031/find-the-sum-frac1-cos0-circ-cos1-circ-frac1-